# Use PostGIS to find all the most outer points

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql

I am trying to use POSTGIS to find all the outer points when I have alot of points? How would I go about doing this and and I cant seem to find a command for it. [image: Goals]

Comment: How do you define an outer point?

Comment: Imagine I took a Box around all my points. Than you split the Box into 8 rows and 2 columns. An outer point would be the point that are closest to the Box wall in each square/cell.

Comment: I was thinking the image would explain well enough?

Comment: Convex hull is what I need correct

Comment: SELECT ST_ASGEOJSON((ST_DumpPoints(ST_ConvexHull(st_collect(geog::geometry)))).geom) FROM sources; made it work using

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for some good comments I made it work using.

```
SELECT ST_ASGEOJSON((ST_DumpPoints(ST_ConvexHull(st_collect(geog::geometry)))).geom) FROM sources;
```